# Strange texture result when mix two camera textures in glsl

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm making a simple image filter app in android and I implemented lowpass filter using same method in GPUImage(https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)

it buffers the previous and current camera frames mixture and render it.
So i created a buffer FBO and render the current camera texture, re-use it as a texture for mixture in lowpass filter shader with next camera texture.

I tested my code with some smartphones(Galaxy S10, Nexus 6P, etc..) and it worked well. However in Galaxy S8(Mali-G71) the result is strange and I don't know what was wrong.

These are the wrong results

[image]
[image]

Here are my code:

```
Fragment shader:
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
uniform sampler2D sTexture1;
uniform float filterStrength;

void main() {
    vec4 texColor0 = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);
    vec4 texColor1 = texture2D(sTexture1, vTextureCoord);
    gl_FragColor = mix(texColor0, texColor1, filterStrength);
}
```

What can cause this results?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The artifacts look tile aligned for Mali, so if I had to guess you are reading the currently bound framebuffer color attachment as an input texture at the same time as writing in to it.

This is "implementation defined" behavior in the specification, and concurrent reads and writes will definitely do bad things on a tile-based renderer like Mali.